# ASP MVC ModelState values are missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a method marked with [HttpPost] with a number of parameters.  When my form is posted I can see that the parameters have the correct values (code == "popppppppp") but when I look in ViewData.ModelState I do not see an entry for "Code" and yet I *do* see an entry for DefaultLeadDays which is a nullable integer.

How can this possibly be the case, and does anyone know what I need to do to fix it?

[image]

Comment: This should not be the case. All parameters should have been shown in `Keys`. Have you solved it yet?

Comment: Sorry but I have no recollection what the problem was, I am quite sure I no longer have it.